# Transparent Panel on Form that has a backgroundimage

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form, that has a BackgroundImage, and the BackColor of form is set to **red**. Then, I try to add a panel on that form, set panel's Background to Transparent, but it inherits Form's BackColor and thus panel's background becomes **red**.

How do I "tell" the panel not to inherit Form's BackColor, but Form's BackgroundImage?

**Update**: It's working fine on Windows 7, but not on Windows XP (SP3).

**Fixed:** The problem was caused by overriding Form's CreateParams and turning on WS_EX_COMPOSITED

Comment: It is not the case when I try it. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Do you want your panel displayed behind of the program ? if you set its background transparent, it must show its parents background.

Comment: tafa: vs2010. yes in visual studio it works, but when i try to debug on Win Xp...it's not working! @icaptan: yes it shows it's parent's background. but it's parent (form) has an backgroundimage ...so i need that

Comment: it works on windows 7 and not on Xp ?

Comment: yes. on xp panel becomes white. on win 7 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Windows Forms ask for the backcolor of the parent control when current control's backcolor is set to transparent.  [Transparent Panel](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

change the panel property BackColor to Transparent [web tab]

Comment: Not sure this answer applies to the question asked.